# Get wifi location with out any data plan in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

My application is able to get the current location when i am connected to the cell site, if my cell site is off am not able to get current location by wifi. But according to location documentation, we can find the current location by wifi also. So i am not able to understand why i am not able to get current location by wifi (cell site off).

Is this possible to get the current location with cell site off?

```java
try { 
    BlackBerryLocationProvider provider = 
        (BlackBerryLocationProvider)LocationProvider.getInstance(new 
             BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE_CELL));
} catch (LocationException) { }
```

Yes i am using the above code for location.

Comment: you will get the location from gps na ?

Comment: I don't want to use GPS here...
I have only option for Wifi and cell site and I am able to get the location if cell site is on. But cell site off the application should be get current location from wifi. that is not working for me.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949

Comment: try { 
BlackBerryLocationProvider provider = 
(BlackBerryLocationProvider)LocationProvider.getInstance(new BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE_CELL)); 
} catch (LocationException) { 
}

Yes i am using the above code for location.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use WLAN based geolocation, you can use this criteria, provided you are in OS >= 6.0:

```
 new BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN);
```

Useful links:
[Location APIs – Start to finish](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949) 
[Simple Location API](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-Location-API/ta-p/1145951)